# Eclipse warning "Replace the type specification in this constructor call with the diamond operator ('<>')" in a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

What does Eclipse mean when it asks to `Replace the type specification in this constructor call with the diamond operator ('<>')`, since the said operator is already there?

Then I put the cursor on what is underlined in blue, and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to learn more, and I get this message (`Replace the type specification in this constructor call with the diamond operator ('<>')`):

[image: An Eclipse warning saying "Replace the type specification in this constructor call with the diamond operator ('<>')"]

And if I delete `Object` from within `<>`, Eclipse still is not happy:

[image: An Eclipse warning saying "Replace the type specification in this constructor call with the diamond operator ('<>')"]

#### EDIT

We made sure that

- `java.util.List` was imported
- changes were saved
- `Project -> Clean...` command was applied

The blue warning still won't go away.

Comment: Check your imports, which `List` are you using?

Comment: @nullpointer That doesn't matter. If OP would use a wrong import, then he would get a different message.

Comment: @nullpointer java.util.List had already been imported

Comment: Did you try a `Project -> Clean...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a **bug in** the [**SonarLint**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint)'s diamond operator checker, not of Eclipse JDT: see [the source code of SonarLint that contains the message](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/DiamondOperatorCheck.java#L84).

See also: [SonarJava Rule 2293: *The diamond operator ("<>") should be used*](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-2293)

**Solution:**

**Disable** the **SonarJava rule 2293** and **use** the **Eclipse warning** ***Generic types > Redundant type argument (1.7 or higher)*** instead.

Answer (score -1):

Save the file(rebuild if Build Automatically is off) and that warning should go away.

Comment: Had already saved, and 'Build automatically' is actually checked, too. The blue warning still won't go away.

Comment: Is this under the Info or Warning section in Eclipse? If its highlighted in blue then I'm assuming its under Info. I would check compiler settings (either global or project scope) for how Eclipse handles Info/Warnings for Generics.